# Will the set be open or closed?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

[image]

The doubt I have is that as (0,0) being included in the set it can be considered as a boundry point. Hence I think it might be neither open nor closed

Comment: What is the topology you took on $\mathbb N$?

Comment: The fact that $A$ contains one of its boundary points does show that $A$ is not open, but you still have to explain why it’s not closed.

Comment: @janmarqz: $\Bbb N$ isn’t being topologized here; it’s just being used to define $A$. $A$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^2$, presumably with the usual topology.

Comment: It is closed. Topological argument: take any point in the complement and see if you can find an open ball around that point that remains in the complement. Analytic argument: show that it contains all its limit points (in essence, this is the same as showing that $(0,0)$ is the only aggregation point).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott...  give Gudu Gudu a chance

Comment: @janmarqz: I am: that’s why I merely pointed out what still needs to be done instead of doing it myself.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott you are a clever savvy man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume that we are dealing with the standard $\mathbb{R}^2$. Otherwise any of the answers can be true depending on the overlying space.

The answer is: **neither open nor closed**.

**Not open:** we will show that by showing that the complement is not closed. Indeed, consider the sequence $v_n=(1+1/n,1)$ which is fully contained in $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash A$ but converges to $(1,1)$ which is in $A$ (corresponding to $n=m=1$). Thus $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash A$ is not closed.

**Not closed:** note that for a fixed $m\in\mathbb{N}$ we have the sequence $v_n=(1/n,1/m)$ which converges to $(0,1/m)$ which is not in $A$.

*Side note:* if $A$ were additionally to include all points of the form $(1/n,0)$, $(0,1/m)$ then it would be closed.